# Error with Microsoft graph, ODataType error with Sendmail

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I have an error occurring that I can't seem to find anything about.  When I run my code I get the following error.  I am not setting oDataType so I assume this is something done by the api itself.

> ServiceException: Code: RequestBodyRead Message: The property 'oDataType' does not exist on type microsoft.graph.itemBody'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type or mark the type as open type.

My code is mostly copied from microsoft samples.

```
  var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
             .Create(clientId)
             .WithTenantId(tenantId)
             .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
             .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority))
             .Build();

            ClientCredentialProvider authenticationProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

            client = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);

 var message = new Microsoft.Graph.Message()
            {
                Subject = "Test email",
                Body = new ItemBody
                {
                    ContentType = BodyType.Text,                 
                    Content = "Test email."                    
                },
                HasAttachments = false,
                ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
                {
                    new Recipient
                    {
                        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                        {
                            Address = "myemail@mydomain.com"
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
           
            var saveToSentItems = false;

            await client.Users[userID].SendMail(message, saveToSentItems).Request().PostAsync();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: (1) Provide the detailed error logs - requestid, timestamp (2) Just to isolate the issue further, I would test the same Graph API call in Microsoft Graph Explorer or POSTMAN and see if you can repro the issue or not.

Comment: Try this way, don't use braces near Message(). See [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request-1).

Comment: I tried after removing the braces.  I even recopied the example and it still throws the same exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I suspect, you're using a older library/build. I [remember the related issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/450) and it's fixed last year itself.
- Please update it with the latest one , try testing the same and let us know if you can still repro the issue or not.

Comment: Unfortunatly this isn't the case.  I am running 3.19.0 which is the newest nuget update (10/27/20).  I even went back and tried a few prior ones to see if it was a new issue.

Comment: It wasn't the Microsoft.Graph library specifically, it was one of the ancillary ones apparently.  I had a number of the azure and graph nuget packages installed along side .graph, .auth and .core and one of them was causing the issue.  Recreating the test app and only importing the necessary packages fixed the issue.  My guess is one of them changed updated something in Microsoft.Graph that broke it.